# Nokia Here Maps missing road segments

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, maps, here

Over the past 8 or so months, I have updated my maps whenever the opportunity arises, but have not yet seen this problem fixed.  I find that on a straight road, there will be a 200 foot gap in the highlighted section of road on the gui, and upon hitting that gap, the gps will go into recalculate mode, even though past this gap, it shows the remainder of the road highlighted. Is it possibly a setting, or a conflict with online vs offline maps that's causing this? Has anyone had this problem and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Can't you add a screenshot? this will help a lot

Comment: Have you reported this issue to Nokia, map errors or glitches cannot be fixed unless someone reports them?

Comment: Are you referring to a particular road where you encounter this error, or is it happening randomly to all roads (including roads which were fine before)? If it's the same road each time, then the GIS data they are using for the roads in that area is incomplete or has not been captured correctly.

Comment: Arabella this happens on almost any road longer than a mile driving around northern VA :: HaLaBi, I will try and grab a screenshot after I unbrick my phone (GDR2)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a problem in the HERE map data, maybe you could tell HERE (or even suggest a change) on http://here.com/mapcreator to get it fixed in the next map data update?